# How to add a count value when pushing to an in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a JSfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Khgbu/4/)

Example:

Every time I click on addField();  the field.id's value goes up by 1.  so that the output isn't an empty string?

EX:

```
fields: [ { "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }  ]
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App', []);

    function Controller($scope) {
        $scope.friends = [];
        $scope.fields = [];

        $scope.addFields = function() {
            $scope.fields.push({id:''});
        };

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <button ng-click="addFields()">
          Add Field
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <input ng-hide="true" checked="checked" type="radio" value="field" ng-model="field.id" />
        <div>{{field.id}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>fields: {{fields | json}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.length` property of `$scope.fields`

```
$scope.addFields = function() {
    var id = $scope.fields.length == undefined ? 0 : $scope.fields.length ;

   $scope.fields.push({id: id + 1});
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Khgbu/6/)